# how to enhance my dataset output using python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have 2 input files, `input.txt` and `datainput.txt`. I check if the 2nd column of `input.txt` matches the 1st column of `datainput.txt`, and if they match, then I put it's `orthodb_id` at the end relevant row in the output file.

input.txt:

```
5 21 218
6 11 1931
7 26 173
```

datainput.txt:

```
>21|95|28|5
Computer
>11|28|5|5
Cate
```

code.py:

```
import csv

with open('input.txt', 'rb') as file1:
    file1_data = dict(line.split(None, 2)[1::-1] for line in file1 if line.strip())

with open('data.txt', 'rb') as file2, open('output.txt', 'wb') as outputfile:
    output = csv.writer(outputfile, delimiter='|')
    for line in file2:
        if line[:1] == '>':
            row = line.strip().split('|')
            key = row[0][1:]
            if key in file1_data:
                 output.writerow(row + [file1_data[key]])
```

This is the output I get with my code:

```
>21|95|28|5|5
>11|28|5|5|6
```

Comment: You would be better off if you use BioPython for reading fasta format input (datainput file).
or see [fastareader](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7654971/parsing-a-fasta-file-using-a-generator-python) very naive example!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need just add an `else` block in your code to get the desired output:

```
import csv

with open('input.txt', 'rb') as file1:
    file1_data = dict(line.split(None, 2)[1::-1] for line in file1 if line.strip())

with open('data.txt', 'rb') as file2, open('output.txt', 'wb') as outputfile:
    output = csv.writer(outputfile, delimiter='|')
    for line in file2:
        if line[:1] == '>':
            row = line.strip().split('|')
            key = row[0][1:]
            if key in file1_data:
                output.writerow(row + [file1_data[key]])
        else:
            outputfile.write(line)
```

Comment: Once you are satisfied with this solution, please submit it to http://codereview.stackexchange.com, to get some useful suggestions on how to improve it.