# Parsing sequences from a FASTA file in python

Tags: python, fasta

I have a text file:

```
>name_1  
data_1  
>name_2  
data_2  
>name_3  
data_3  
>name_4    
data_4  
>name_5  
data_5
```

I want to store header (`name_1`, `name_2`....) in one list and data (`data_1`, `data_2`....) in another list in a Python program.

```
def parse_fasta_file(fasta):
    desc=[]    
    seq=[]    
    seq_strings = fasta.strip().split('>')  
    for s in seq_strings:  
        if len(s):  
            sects = s.split()  
            k = sects[0]  
            v = ''.join(sects[1:])  
    desc.append(k)  
    seq.append(v)    

  for l in sys.stdin:  
  data = open('D:\python\input.txt').read().strip()  
  parse_fasta_file(data)
  print seq
```

this is my code which i have tried but i am not able to get the answer.

Comment: What have you written so far? Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: Have you even tried writing anything yet??

Comment: I am new to python and have tried it.. i am able to do for one but not able to do when multiple files are there.

Comment: Show us your code and we can show you how to fix it.  A blanket "how do I do this" leaves too many things to explain because we can't know what you don't know.

Comment: def parse_fasta_file(fasta):
    seq_strings = fasta.strip().split('>')
    for s in seq_strings:
        if len(s):
            sects = s.split()
            k = sects[0]
            v = ''.join(sects[1:])
    desc.append(k)
    seq.append(v)

Comment: I lifted that into the question.  Please verify that the indentation came out correctly.  You can't really post Python code in comments because whitespace is important.

Comment: What do you pass in as `fasta`?  A list of lines read from the file?

Comment: possible duplicate of [parsing a fasta file using a generator ( python )](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7654971/parsing-a-fasta-file-using-a-generator-python)

Comment: See also https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyfasta/

Comment: Iam passing the fasta file in "fasta".

Comment: The file name, an opened file name, or the contents of the file as a list of strings, one per line?

Comment: If the indentation is right, you have some trivial indentation errors.  But please verify again, and see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most fundamental error is trying to access a variable outside of its scope.

```
def function (stuff):
    seq = whatever

function('data')
print seq   ############ error
```

You cannot access `seq` outside of `function`.  The usual way to do this is to have `function` return a value, and capture it in a variable within the caller.

```
def function (stuff):
    seq = whatever
    return seq

s = function('data')
print s
```

(I have deliberately used different variable names inside the function and outside.  Inside `function` you cannot access `s` or `data`, and outside, you cannot access `stuff` or `seq`.  Incidentally, it would be quite okay, but confusing to a beginner, to use a different variable with the same name `seq` in the mainline code.)

With that out of the way, we can attempt to write a function which returns a list of sequences and a list of descriptions for them.

```
def parse_fasta (lines):
    descs = []
    seqs = []
    data = ''
    for line in lines:
        if line.startswith('>'):
            if data:   # have collected a sequence, push to seqs
                seqs.append(data)
                data = ''
            descs.append(line[1:])  # Trim '>' from beginning
        else:
            data += line.rstrip('\r\n')
    # there will be yet one more to push when we run out
    seqs.append(data)
    return descs, seqs
```

This isn't particularly elegant, but should get you started.  A better design would be to return a list of (description, data) tuples where the description and its data are closely coupled together.

```
descriptions, sequences = parse_fasta(open('file', 'r').read().split('\n'))
```

The `sys.stdin` loop in your code does not appear to do anything useful.

Comment: The proposed duplicate has much better solutions.  The use of a generator would help avoid reading an entire file into memory at once.

Comment: where did you define "data" ??

Comment: its not working. When I am printing sequences it is giving me result :::  ['name_1ATCCAGCT', 'name_2GGGCAACT', 'name_3ATGGATCT', 'name_4AAGCAACC', 'name_5TTGGAACT', 'name_6ATGCCATT', 'name_7ATGGCACT']

Comment: It should store the name in the description but it is storing it into sequences.

Comment: Sorry, I was missing a split('\n') as well.  Sloppy testing on my part. Apologies.