# How can I check whether a given file is FASTA?

Tags: python, user-input

I am designing a code that requires a .fasta file to be input at one of the early stages. Right now, I am validating the input using this function:

```
def file_validation(fasta):
    while True:
        try:
            file_name= str(raw_input(fasta))
        except IOError:
            print("Please give the name of the fasta file that exists in the folder!")
            continue

        if not(file_name.endswith(".fasta")):
            print("Please give the name of the file with the .fasta extension!")
        else:
            break
    return file_name
```

Now, although this function works fine, there is still some room for error in the sense that a user could potentially maybe input a file that, while having a file name that ends with .fasta, could have some non-.fasta content inside. What could I do to prevent this and let the user know that his/her .fasta file is corrupted?

Comment: Write a fasta parser or find an existing one online.

Comment: I know *nothing* about fasta myself. However, there's an answer that might be useful to you at https://stackoverflow.com/a/7655072/131187. I would say, try to parse a few hundred characters, assuming that make sense. Accept the file if the parse succeeds.

Comment: @Kevin I tried using the Biopython SeqIO 'SeqIO.parse(file_name, 'fasta'))' as part of the conditional tree in order to see if parsing was possible. Sadly, it does not function in warning the user that the file is not a valid .fasta file. Is this what you meant?

Comment: @BillBell I sadly am not up to level to understand certain parts of the code you linked. Do you think I could copy and paste it right into my function in order for it to tell the user that their file is not in the proper .fasta format?

Comment: I see that your question has been answered!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why not just parse the file as if it were FASTA and see whether it breaks?

Using [`biopython`](http://biopython.org/wiki/SeqIO), which silently fails by returning an empty generator on non-FASTA files:

```
from Bio import SeqIO

my_file = "example.csv"  # Obviously not FASTA

def is_fasta(filename):
    with open(filename, "r") as handle:
        fasta = SeqIO.parse(handle, "fasta")
        return any(fasta)  # False when `fasta` is empty, i.e. wasn't a FASTA file

is_fasta(my_file)
# False
```

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to integrate the part of the code starting at 'with open(filename)....' into my function, and I'm having difficulty making work still. Do you think I should just make this a separate function and then call it in my original validation function?

Comment: This already is a freestanding function, so you should be able to call it from within your validation function. Could you clarify your intent?

Comment: I just wanted to make sure that my code didn't break, and would continue to prompt the user for a valid answer. And your set up did work in the end! thank you very much.

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy can you comment on mine https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/15050/biopython-seqio-check-input-file

Answer (score 0):

[Biopython SeqIO](https://biopython.org/wiki/SeqIO) will generate a `Bio.SeqIO.FastaIO.FastaIterator` even with an empty file as imput.

Probably not the most elegant solution. Iterating through every line and check for ">" character:

```
# Validate fasta file
fastafile = open("sequences.fasta", "r")
for line in fastafile:
    texit = False
    if not line.startswith('>'):
        texit = True
    try:
        line = next(fastafile)
    except:
        texit = True
    if line.startswith('>'):
        texit = True
    if texit:
        print("The file provided does not appear to be a proper FASTA file!")
        exit()
fastafile.close()
```