# How I can parallelize computations in a fasta file, where each processor takes one sequence

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, fork, python-multithreading

I don't know how to parallelise a code in Python that takes each line of a FASTA file and makes some statistics, like compute GC content, of it. Do you have some tips or libraries that will help me to decrease the time spent in execution?

I've tried to use os.fork(), but it gives me more execution time than the sequential code. Probably is due to I don't know very well how to give each child a different sequence.

```py
#Computing GC Content
from Bio import SeqIO                  
with open('chr1.fa', 'r') as f:
    records = list (SeqIO.parse(f,'fasta'))
    GC_for_sequence=[]
    for i in records:
        GC=0
        for j in i:
            if j in "GC":
                GC+=1
        GC_for_sequence.append(GC/len(i))
    print(GC_for_sequence)
```

The expected execution would be: Each process takes one sequence, and they do the statistics in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

a few notes on your existing code to start with:

1. I'd suggest not doing: `list (SeqIO.parse(…))` as that will pause execution until all sequences have been loaded in memory, you're much better off (memory and total execution time) just leaving it as an iterator and consuming elements off to workers as needed
2. looping over each character is pretty slow, using `str.count` is going to be **much** faster

putting this together, you can do:

```
from Bio import SeqIO

with open('chr1.fa') as fd:
    gc_for_sequence=[]
    for seq in SeqIO.parse(fd, 'fasta'):
        gc = sum(seq.seq.count(base) for base in "GC")
        gc_for_sequence.append(gc / len(seq))
```

if this still isn't fast enough, then you can use the `multiprocessing` module like:

```
from Bio import SeqIO
from multiprocessing import Pool

def sequence_gc_prop(seq):
    return sum(seq.count(base) for base in "GC") / len(seq)

with open('chr1.fa') as fd, Pool() as pool:
    gc_for_sequence = pool.map(
        sequence_gc_prop,
        (seq.seq for seq in SeqIO.parse(fd, 'fasta')),
        chunksize=1000,
    )
```

comments from Lukasz mostly apply.  other non-obvious stuff:

- the weird `seq.seq for seq in…` stuff is to make sure that we're not Pickling unnecessary data
- I'm setting `chunksize` to quite a large value because the function should be quick, hence we want to give children a reasonable amount of work to do so the parent process doesn't spend all its time orchestrating things

Comment: Thank you! So, in the input data inside the pool.map function (seq.seq for seq in SeqIO.parse(fd, 'fasta')) the module takes every line of my file and calculates the GC content in a parallel way?

Comment: should do!  you could run `top` at the same time to make sure it's actually running across multiple processors.  at a guess: this sort of task isn't very suited to running in parallel, the amount of useful work that can be distributed to each processor is limited.  meaning that the main process will be spending most of its time reading data and coordinating.  reframing the problem would help, e.g. processing multiple files at once

Answer (score 0):

Here's one idea with standard [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html) module:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import numpy as np

no_cores_to_use = 4

GC_for_sequence = [np.random.rand(100) for x in range(10)]

with Pool(no_cores_to_use) as pool:
    result = pool.map(np.average, GC_for_sequence)

print(result)
```

In the code I used `numpy` module to simulate a list with some content. `pool.map`  takes function that you want to use on your data as first argument and data list as second. The function you can easily define yourself. By default, it should take a single argument. If you want to pass more, then use `functools.partial`.

[EDIT] Here's an example  much closer to your problem:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import numpy as np

records = ['ACTGTCGCAGC' for x in range(10)]
no_cores_to_use = 4

def count(sequence):
    count = sequence.count('GC')
    return count

with Pool(no_cores_to_use) as pool:
    result = pool.map(count, records)

print(sum(result))
```

Comment: OK! But If I want to put a large number of different sequences, do I need to put them in a list like the one that you have done in records?

Comment: From your code it looks like you start with a list ( `list (SeqIO.parse(f,'fasta'))` ), so there's no need to do anything extra.

Comment: And the module would work if I add the data as a stdin making a "cat" of the file(in the shell)?

Comment: You could make it work, but it would be very inefficient. Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7654971/parsing-a-fasta-file-using-a-generator-python In short, either use explicit generator that is given there or use iterator `SeqIO.parse("filename", "fasta")` In your code you turn the generator into the list. Don't. Just pass the iterator to the `map`.