# How to extract a subset of protein sequences from a big fasta file with python?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, fasta

I'd like to extract a subset of protein sequences from a .fasta file (`swissprot_canonical-isoforms.fasta`) in a new file (`selected_proteins.fasta`) if protein IDs are listed in a txt file (`Interested proteins.txt`).

Below shows part of protein sequences in the `swissprot_canonical-isoforms.fasta`. Protein IDs are shown between two "|" in the lines that start with ">". For example, "P04637" is a protein ID.

> ```
> >sp|P04637|P53_HUMAN Cellular tumor antigen p53 OS=Homo sapiens GN=TP53 PE=1 SV=4
> MEEPQSDPSVEPPLSQETFSDLWKLLPENNVLSPLPSQAMDDLMLSPDDIEQWFTEDPGP
> DEAPRMPEAAPPVAPAPAAPTPAAPAPAPSWPLSSSVPSQKTYQGSYGFRLGFLHSGTAK
> SVTCTYSPALNKMFCQLAKTCPVQLWVDSTPPPGTRVRAMAIYKQSQHMTEVVRRCPHHE
> RCSDSDGLAPPQHLIRVEGNLRVEYLDDRNTFRHSVVVPYEPPEVGSDCTTIHYNYMCNS
> SCMGGMNRRPILTIITLEDSSGNLLGRNSFEVRVCACPGRDRRTEEENLRKKGEPHHELP
> PGSTKRALPNNTSSSPQPKKKPLDGEYFTLQIRGRERFEMFRELNEALELKDAQAGKEPG
> GSRAHSSHLKSKKGQSTSRHKKLMFKTEGPDSD
> >sp|P04637-2|P53_HUMAN Isoform 2 of Cellular tumor antigen p53 OS=Homo sapiens GN=TP53
> MEEPQSDPSVEPPLSQETFSDLWKLLPENNVLSPLPSQAMDDLMLSPDDIEQWFTEDPGP
> DEAPRMPEAAPPVAPAPAAPTPAAPAPAPSWPLSSSVPSQKTYQGSYGFRLGFLHSGTAK
> SVTCTYSPALNKMFCQLAKTCPVQLWVDSTPPPGTRVRAMAIYKQSQHMTEVVRRCPHHE
> RCSDSDGLAPPQHLIRVEGNLRVEYLDDRNTFRHSVVVPYEPPEVGSDCTTIHYNYMCNS
> SCMGGMNRRPILTIITLEDSSGNLLGRNSFEVRVCACPGRDRRTEEENLRKKGEPHHELP
> PGSTKRALPNNTSSSPQPKKKPLDGEYFTLQDQTSFQKENC
> >sp|P04637-3|P53_HUMAN Isoform 3 of Cellular tumor antigen p53 OS=Homo sapiens GN=TP53
> MEEPQSDPSVEPPLSQETFSDLWKLLPENNVLSPLPSQAMDDLMLSPDDIEQWFTEDPGP
> DEAPRMPEAAPPVAPAPAAPTPAAPAPAPSWPLSSSVPSQKTYQGSYGFRLGFLHSGTAK
> SVTCTYSPALNKMFCQLAKTCPVQLWVDSTPPPGTRVRAMAIYKQSQHMTEVVRRCPHHE
> RCSDSDGLAPPQHLIRVEGNLRVEYLDDRNTFRHSVVVPYEPPEVGSDCTTIHYNYMCNS
> SCMGGMNRRPILTIITLEDSSGNLLGRNSFEVRVCACPGRDRRTEEENLRKKGEPHHELP
> PGSTKRALPNNTSSSPQPKKKPLDGEYFTLQMLLDLRWCYFLINSS
> ```

Here are some protein IDs listed in the `Interested proteins.txt`

```
Q6ZWH5
Q8NG66
P51955
P51957
P04629
```

The final output should look like this (only listed the sequence for Q6ZWH5 as an example) :

```
>sp|Q6ZWH5|NEK10_HUMAN Serine/threonine-protein kinase Nek10 OS=Homo sapiens GN=NEK10 PE=2 SV=3
MPDQDKKVKTTEKSTDKQQEITIRDYSDLKRLRCLLNVQSSKQQLPAINFDSAQNSMTKS
EPAIRAGGHRARGQWHESTEAVELENFSINYKNERNFSKHPQRKLFQEIFTALVKNRLIS
REWVNRAPSIHFLRVLICLRLLMRDPCYQEILHSLGGIENLAQYMEIVANEYLGYGEEQH
TVDKLVNMTYIFQKLAAVKDQREWVTTSGAHKTLVNLLGARDTNVLLGSLLALASLAESQ
ECREKISELNIVENLLMILHEYDLLSKRLTAELLRLLCAEPQVKEQVKLYEGIPVLLSLL
HSDHLKLLWSIVWILVQVCEDPETSVEIRIWGGIKQLLHILQGDRNFVSDHSSIGSLSSA
NAAGRIQQLHLSEDLSPREIQENTFSLQAACCAALTELVLNDTNAHQVVQENGVYTIAKL
ILPNKQKNAAKSNLLQCYAFRALRFLFSMERNRPLFKRLFPTDLFEIFIDIGHYVRDISA
YEELVSKLNLLVEDELKQIAENIESINQNKAPLKYIGNYAILDHLGSGAFGCVYKVRKHS
GQNLLAMKEVNLHNPAFGKDKKDRDSSVRNIVSELTIIKEQLYHPNIVRYYKTFLENDRL
YIVMELIEGAPLGEHFSSLKEKHHHFTEERLWKIFIQLCLALRYLHKEKRIVHRDLTPNN
IMLGDKDKVTVTDFGLAKQKQENSKLTSVVGTILYSCPEVLKSEPYGEKADVWAVGCILY
QMATLSPPFYSTNMLSLATKIVEAVYEPVPEGIYSEKVTDTISRCLTPDAEARPDIVEVS
SMISDVMMKYLDNLSTSQLSLEKKLERERRRTQRYFMEANRNTVTCHHELAVLSHETFEK
ASLSSSSSGAASLKSELSESADLPPEGFQASYGKDEDRACDEILSDDNFNLENAEKDTYS
EVDDELDISDNSSSSSSSPLKESTFNILKRSFSASGGERQSQTRDFTGGTGSRPRPALLP
LDLLLKVPPHMLRAHIKEIEAELVTGWQSHSLPAVILRNLKDHGPQMGTFLWQASAGIAV
SQRKVRQISDPIQQILIQLHKIIYITQLPPALHHNLKRRVIERFKKSLFSQQSNPCNLKS
EIKKLSQGSPEPIEPNFFTADYHLLHRSSGGNSLSPNDPTGLPTSIELEEGITYEQMQTV
IEEVLEESGYYNFTSNRYHSYPWGTKNHPTKR
```

Is there any way to do this with python? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Some resources that will help: 1. Use [Biopython](https://biopython.org/) 2. [See example #4 here](http://training.scicomp.jic.ac.uk/docs/python_for_biologists_book/parsing_fasta_files.html#exercises) 3. [Parsing Fasta files with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7655072/1431750) 4. Other [SO questions involving Fasta and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=fasta+%5Bpython%5D)

Comment: @aneriod: do not forget [the official Python Absolute Beginners' Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/) – you don't know OP's level of Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `pyfasta`, an interface to the FASTA format from python.

```
from pyfasta import Fasta

f = Fasta('fasta.fa') # open the file

targets = {"P04637"} # define your target IDs

selection = {}

for key in f:
    candidateKey = key.split("|")[1]
    if candidateKey in targets:
        selection[key] = f[key][:]
        print(key)
        print(selection[key])
```

Output:

```
sp|P04637|P53_HUMAN Cellular tumor antigen p53 OS=Homo sapiens GN=TP53 PE=1 SV=4
MEEPQSDPSVEPPLSQETFSDLWKLLPENNVLSPLPSQAMDDLMLSPDDIEQWFTEDPGPDEAPRMPEAAPPVAPAPAAP
TPAAPAPAPSWPLSSSVPSQKTYQGSYGFRLGFLHSGTAKSVTCTYSPALNKMFCQLAKTCPVQLWVDSTPPPGTRVRAM
AIYKQSQHMTEVVRRCPHHERCSDSDGLAPPQHLIRVEGNLRVEYLDDRNTFRHSVVVPYEPPEVGSDCTTIHYNYMCNS
SCMGGMNRRPILTIITLEDSSGNLLGRNSFEVRVCACPGRDRRTEEENLRKKGEPHHELPPGSTKRALPNNTSSSPQPKK
KPLDGEYFTLQIRGRERFEMFRELNEALELKDAQAGKEPGGSRAHSSHLKSKKGQSTSRHKKLMFKTEGPDSD
```

Comment: Thanks for answering my question! It is very useful. But the output format is different to what I want. I don't want a dictionary. Is there a way to covert that to what I listed above?

Comment: I edited my answer to print the output nicely in addition to storing it in a dictionary. If you want to save this information to a file, you can do that similarly.